# How to fill everything on one side of path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, fillbetween, fill

Consider I have some image. I want to "cut away" part of an image using a double lined arc (see page 110 of the TikZ/PGF manual). This can be done with the following MWE

```
documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,fit,decorations.pathreplacing,chains,positioning,angles,quotes, fadings}  
\usepackage{xcolor}    
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (0,0){\includegraphics{SampleImage.png}};
  \coordinate (O) at (0.6,1.962);
  \coordinate (A) at (2.82,0.35);
  \coordinate (O1) at (0.665,1.962);
  \coordinate (A1) at (2.82,0.414);

  \draw[line width=0.62pt,double distance=2pt] (O) to [bend right=44] (A);
  \draw [red] (O1) to [bend right=44] (A1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For the purposes of this question, it suffices to take `SampleImage.png` here to be the box: `\filldraw[black!50] (0,0) -- (0,1.962) -- (2.82,1.962) -- (2.82,0) -- cycle;`.

Question is: how can I fill all contents to the right of the double lined arc with white colour so that everything to the right of the arc disappears? I have used the section: `Filling a Path` on page 110 of the TikZ manual. However, fill does not cover the top right corner.

Currently, my work around is to creat another path (the red line above) which was much larger such that the right image *is* covered and then I converted this path to `\filldraw[white]`.

I'm searching for a more efficient method to this brute force approach.

Comment: How big is your image? Does fill cower all to right image border? Can you provide a sketch, what you like have?

Comment: @Zarko, in my case, fill does not cover the top right corner. I've created another path which was much larger such that the right image is covered and then did `\filldraw[white]`. However, I'm searching for a more efficient method.

Comment: @Zarko, more info added to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\fill[white] ([yshift=1pt]O) to [bend right=44] ([xshift=1pt]A) |- cycle;
```

as in

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%\node at (0,0){\includegraphics{SampleImage.png}};
  \filldraw[black!50] (0,0) -- (0,1.962) -- (2.82,1.962) -- (2.82,0) -- cycle;
  \coordinate (O) at (0.6,1.962);
  \coordinate (A) at (2.82,0.35);
  \coordinate (O1) at (0.665,1.962);
  \coordinate (A1) at (2.82,0.414);
  \fill[white] ([yshift=1pt]O) to [bend right=44] ([xshift=1pt]A) |- cycle;
  \draw[line width=0.62pt,double distance=2pt] (O) to [bend right=44] (A);

  \draw [red] (O1) to [bend right=44] (A1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, `|- cycle` means "close the path via a rectangle corner", and little shifts were introduced to make sure everything is covered (in the graphics the shifts may not be needed, they come from `\filldraw` which adds the line width to the filled area).

If you want a dashed line, you can use `preaction` or `post action`. Because there can be viewer-dependent artifacts, it may be better to add another white line on top.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\node at (0,0){\includegraphics{SampleImage.png}};
  \filldraw[black!50] (0,0) -- (0,1.962) -- (2.82,1.962) -- (2.82,0) -- cycle;
  \coordinate (O) at (0.6,1.962);
  \coordinate (A) at (2.82,0.35);
  \coordinate (O1) at (0.665,1.962);
  \coordinate (A1) at (2.82,0.414);
  \fill[white] ([yshift=1pt]O) to [bend right=44] ([xshift=1pt]A) |- cycle;
  \draw[preaction={solid,double=white,line width=0.62pt,double distance=2pt},
     draw=black,double distance=2pt,line width=0.62pt,dashed,
     postaction={solid,draw=white,line width=2pt}] (O) to
     [bend right=44] (A);
  \draw [red] (O1) to [bend right=44] (A1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Wasn't aware of this feature. A separate question, but do you know how to make the arc have a dashed line? i.e. `\draw[line width=0.62pt,double distance=2pt, dashed] (O) to [bend right=44] (A);` even dashes the white fill. However, I only want the black lines dashed. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sid This is slightly more tricky, also because of viewer artifacts. I added a dashed version.

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thank you very much!